# how display database values in combobox if select combobox

Tags: c#

How to display database values in combobox if select combobox 
I want to display item name in combobox(cboItemName) according to combobox item type(cboItemType) from database please help. . .

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Rough example:

```
cboItemType.DisplayMember = "Name"; // or property that you want to display
cboItemType.ValueMember = "ID"; // or property for the value

cboItemType.DataSource =
   database
   .ItemTypes
   .Where(someFilter)
   .ToList();

// to get selected value:

if (cboItemType.SelectedIndex == -1)
   return; // nothing selected

int selectedItemTypeID = (int)cboItemType.SelectedValue;
var selectedItemType =
   database
   .ItemTypes
   .Single(itemType => itemType.ID == selectedItemTypeID);

// do something with selectedItemType
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];  // ds(DataSet Obj) 
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "cboItemName"; // column that to be displayed  
comboBox1.ValueMember = "cboItemType";  //  column name accourding to which value is displayed
```